# Flutter : Move widget to another position

Tags: flutter

[image]

On pressing the button, i want the text (Text to move up) to reach the top of the screen and display a new text in the center.

I think stack and positioned widget might work.
I would like to have a responsive app.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MoveTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MoveTestState createState() => _MoveTestState();
}

class _MoveTestState extends State<MoveTest> {
  bool moveIt = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Text to move up',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          (moveIt)
              ? Container(
                  child: Text(
                    'New Text in the center',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(),
          Container(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  moveIt = true;
                });
              },
              child: Text('Move'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How do i move the text with little animation and display new widget with some text?
Should i use stack with positioned widget?
How to use stack/positioned widget and responsive app?

Edit:

Are you getting happiness by giving negative vote without giving any help?  Cruel mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with a SlideTransition (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SlideTransition-class.html) and upon finishing up the animation which you can control with an Animation object you submit to SlideTranslation, you can show whatever text in the middle.

Small code example to kickstart your efforts.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter SlideTransition',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: MyHomePage()
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();

}


class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
    _animation = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0, 0), end: Offset(0, -0.4)).animate(
        _animationController);

    _animationController.forward().whenComplete(() {
      // put here the stuff you wanna do when animation completed!
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: SlideTransition(
          position: _animation,
          child: Center(child: Text("My Text")),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I did with stack and positioned widget. But yours looks great. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahesh can you share your code for how you did it with stack and positioned widget? I'm trying to solve this same problem too. Maybe add another answer here